# назначение интерфейса в java

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

привожу пример из некоего сайта:

```
public interface Swimmable  {
     public void swim();
}

public class Duck implements Swimmable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        duck.swim();
    }
    public void swim() {
        System.out.println("Уточка, плыви!");
    }
}
```

для чего нужен interface
если можно просто:

```
public class Duck {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duck duck = new Duck();
    duck.swim();
  }
  public void swim() {
    System.out.println("Уточка, плыви!");
  }
}
```

с тем же результатом

Comment: Если очень кратко — потому что плавать может не только утка. Но конкретно этот пример какой-то глупый, непонятно зачем в утке метод main

Comment: Вы можете создать еще класс `Ship`, который имплементирует `Swimmable`, т.е. умеет плавать, но по другому. И еще Какие топлавающие сущности,  занести всех в коллекцию и в цикле отправить всех в плавание. Например...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, что Alexey имел ввиду следующее: Возможно автор кода предполагал, что ему понадобится ещё какой-нибудь класс, в котором нужен будет метод swim(). То есть если у вас есть много классов (пусть рыба, утка, черепаха, лебедь), то у всех их будет общий метод swim(). В таком случае принято создавать интерфейс, чтобы показать, что у каждого из данных классов есть методы из созданного интерфейса.

Answer (score 5):

Интерфейсы нужны для того, чтобы можно было придавать общее поведение классам, относящимся к разным иерархиям наследования. Бывают плавающие рыбы, плавающие птицы, плавающие млекопитающие и так далее. Не все животные, не все птицы и не все млекопитающие умеют плавать, но утка и кит умеют плавать, при том, что утка не является потомком кита, а кит не является потомком утки.

Значит, мы не можем сделать метод `swim` в классе `животное`, от которого наследуются птицы, рыбы и млекопитающие, не можем также сделать такой метод в классах `птица` и `млекопитающее`. Однако мы можем захотеть иметь список разных плавающих животных и заставить их всех по очереди плавать, даже если не знаем, к какому конкретному классу относится очередное животное. Выражаясь по-умному, нужно обеспечить полиморфизм между объектами, относящимися к различным иерархиям наследования.

Существует два способа разрешить это противоречие -- множественное наследование, когда класс `утка` может быть потомком класса `птица` и потомком класса `водоплавающее` одновременно, и интерфейсы, когда класс `утка` является потомком класса `птица`, и при этом реализует интерфейс `водоплавающее`.

По мнению создателей `Java` (с которым лично я согласен), множественное наследование усложняет язык и влечет за собой ряд трудноразрешимых проблем, поэтому `Java` предоставляет интерфейсы, но не разрешает множественного наследования (каждый класс может являться потомком только одного другого класса).

С использованием интерфейсов полиморфизм между объектами из разных иерархий наследования обеспечивается примерно таким образом:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnimalFarm {

  interface Swimming { // Все, кто реализует этот интерфейс, должны уметь плавать 
    public void swim(); 
  }

  abstract class Animal { // Все животные едят 
    abstract public void eat() ; 
  }

  abstract class Bird extends Animal {
    abstract public void fly() ; // Птицы еще умеют летать
    abstract public void layEggs() ; // и откладывать яйца
  }

  abstract class Mammal extends Animal {
    abstract public void bearAYoung() ; // Млекопитающие рожают детенышей
  }

  abstract class Fish extends Animal implements Swimming { // Все рыбы умеют плавать
    abstract public void spawn() ; // А еще мечут икру
  }

  class Duck extends Bird implements Swimming { // Утка умеет плавать
    @Override public void eat() { System.out.println("The Duck is eating"); } 
    @Override public void fly() { System.out.println("The Duck is flying"); };
    @Override public void layEggs() { System.out.println("The Duck is laying eggs"); };
    @Override public void swim() { System.out.println("The Duck is swimming"); };; 
  }

  class Hen extends Bird { // Курица не умеет плавать
    @Override public void eat() { System.out.println("The Duck is eating"); } 
    @Override public void fly() { System.out.println("The Duck is flying"); };
    @Override public void layEggs() { System.out.println("The Duck is laying eggs"); };
  }

  class Dolphin extends Mammal implements Swimming { // Дельфин умеет плавать
    @Override public void eat() { System.out.println("Дельфин ест рыбу"); }; 
    @Override public void bearAYoung() { System.out.println("Дельфин рожает дельфиненка"); };
    @Override public void swim() { System.out.println("Дельфин плывет"); }; 
  }

  class Cat extends Mammal { // Кошка не умеет плавать
    @Override public void eat() { System.out.println("Кошка ест мышку"); }; 
    @Override public void bearAYoung() { System.out.println("Кошка рожает котенка"); };
  }

  class Salmon extends Fish { // Лосось -- рыба, значит, умеет плавать
    @Override public void eat() { System.out.println("Лосось ест не знаю что"); }; 
    @Override public void swim() { System.out.println("Лосось плывет"); }; 
    @Override public void spawn() { System.out.println("Лосось мечет икру"); };
  }

  private void run () {
    List<Swimming> waterDwellers = new ArrayList<>(); // Вместо класса указываем интерфейс

    waterDwellers.add(new Salmon());    // Рыбы,  
    waterDwellers.add(new Duck());    // Птицы, умеющие плавать
    waterDwellers.add(new Dolphin()); // Млекопитающие, умеющие плавать 

    for (Swimming animal: waterDwellers) { //
        animal.swim();                              // Все умеют плавать
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    new AnimalFarm().run();
  }

}
```

Ну и всё-таки читайте учебники, у Шилдта и Экеля всё это очень хорошо описано.

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно понять, что вам нужно - Duck или Swimmable. Думаю согласитесь, что это разные функциональные сущности. Если в вашей программе будет нужен именно Swimmable, то вы и создаете интерфейс для этих целей.

Comment: почему же тогда для Duck создаётся класс а для Swimmable интерфейс. этого я не могу понять

Comment: Потому что это разные сущности. Duck он только Duck и ничего более. Он может дать функционал только Duck. Swimmable - интерфейс, который могут имплементировать разные классы, теоритически их может быть много. Например, class Fish implements Swimmable.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться у минусующих, что не так с ответом по их мнению?